# How to write OrderByDescending for taking last record

Tags: c#, linq

Please Help me How can i take last Record from Application Tracking Table Im getting Error as cant convert Table name to string

```
var _agencySortData = (from n in _context.tbl_farmer_master
                       where n.fm_registration_id == FarmerregId
                       join _status in _context.tbl_status on n.fm_status equals _status.status_id
                       join _track in _context.tbl_application_tracking on n.fm_registration_id.ToString() equals _track.at_application_number

                       select new FarmerDetails
                       {
                           at_registration_id = n.fm_registration_id,
                           CreatedDate = n.fm_creation_datetime,
                           statusID = n.fm_status,
                           StatusMessage = _status.status_desc,


//Here How can i take Last record value
  RemarkMessage = _context.tbl_application_tracking
                                                .Where(c => c.at_application_number == FarmerregId.ToString()).OrderByDescending(x=>x.at_status).Take(1)
                               }).firstordefault();
        return _agencySortData;
    }
```

Comment: What is currently wrong with your code? what is it returning?

Comment: Where are you converting table name to string in all this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `RemarkMessage` is a string type,
Then you need to select your column `Select(r => r.RemarkMessage).FirstOrDefault()` after `OrderByDescending(x=>x.at_status)`

```
var remarkMessage = _context.tbl_application_tracking
    .Where(c => c.at_application_number == FarmerregId.ToString())
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.at_status)
    .Select(r => r.RemarkMessage)
    .FirstOrDefault()
```